# How to do a wget call via proxy with python?

Tags: python, wget, google-scholar

I tried to use this script [pdfmeat](http://code.google.com/p/pdfmeat/) to get data about papers from google scholar.

This script works very well in my pc, but when I try to put this script in my server I don't have results. I saw that is very probably that my server is in the black list of google scholar, give that I have an error (redirects to solve a chapta):

```
$ wget scholar.google.com
--2011-08-08 04:52:19--  http://scholar.google.com/
Resolving scholar.google.com... 72.14.204.147, 72.14.204.99, 72.14.204.103, ...
Connecting to scholar.google.com|72.14.204.147|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.com/sorry/?continue=http://scholar.google.com/ [following]
--2011-08-08 04:52:24--  http://www.google.com/sorry/?continue=http://scholar.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 74.125.93.147, 74.125.93.99, 74.125.93.103, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|74.125.93.147|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2011-08-08 04:52:24 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

Then I have found that there is an option in wget --execute "http_proxy=urltoproxy". I did that

```
wget -e "http_proxy=oneHttpProxy" scholar.google.com
```

and I could save the index.html from google scholar.

Then I tried to the same with the pdfmeat.py I don't have results neither.

this is the code:

```
def getWebdata(self, link, referer='http://scholar.google.com'):
    useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100214 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.5.8'
    c_web = 'wget --execute "http_proxy=oneHttpProxy" -qO- --user-agent="%s" --load-cookies="%s" "%s" --referer="%s"' % (useragent, WGET_COOKIEFILE, link, referer) 
    c_out = os.popen(c_web)
    c_txt = c_out.read()
    c_out.close()
    if re.search("We're sorry", c_txt) or re.search("please type the characters", c_txt):
        self.logger.critical("scholar captcha")
        if not self.options.quiet:
            print "PDFMEAT: scholar captcha!"
        sys.exit()
    self.logger.debug("getwebdata excerpt: %s" % (re.sub("\n", " ", c_txt[0:255])))
    self.queryLog.append("getwebdata excerpt: %s" % (re.sub("\n", " ", c_txt[0:255])))
    return c_txt
```

The script use the module os. The original function is without the --execute option for wget.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just setting the http_proxy env. var.?

So:

$ export http_proxy="oneHttpProxy"

$ python pdfmeat.py ....

Comment: Could you just try 1st with your raw wget command 1st, so: $ http_proxy=http://your_http_proxy wget http://scholar.google.com

Comment: the problem right now is that the script is in a server very important and I don't know the scope of that variable